# JS_Parse_Error from aurelia-bundler when updating TypeScript target to ES6

Tags: typescript, aurelia, systemjs, uglifyjs

I am having an issue which seems to be preventing me from using async/await (or even yield/generators).

I began with the aurelia skeleton for typescript & asp5 (aspnetcore). The default target was set to es5. I would like to use async/await within my TypeScript code so I am trying to update the target to es6.

After updating the tsconfig.json from es5 to es6, a few things happen. First, a lot of duplication errors (which I managed to resolve). The remaining concern is the error I get from the dependencies within aurelia-bundler.

Note: Assume this as the root for the file paths in the stack trace: C:\My\My.App\src\My.App.Web\node_modules\aurelia-bundler\node_modules\systemjs-builder

```
[13:37:07] 'bundle-dev' errored after 1.17 s

[13:37:07] Error: Unexpected token: name (App) (line: 13, col: 8, pos: 594)

Error

at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1526:18)
at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1534:11)
at croak (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2026:9)
at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2034:9)
at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2040:9)
at semicolon (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2060:56)
at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2240:73)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2113:19)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2073:24)
at block_ (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2353:20)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2326:25)
at function_ (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2331:15)
at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2546:24)
at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2716:19)
at expr_ops (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2751:24)
at maybe_conditional (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2756:20)
at maybe_assign (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2780:20)
at expression (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2799:20)
at expr_list (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2565:24)
at subscripts (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2699:30)
at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2552:20)
at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2716:19)
at minify (C:\..\lib\output.js:79:11)
at exports.writeOutputs (C:\..\lib\output.js:153:14)
at C:\..\lib\builder.js:642:14
at tryCatcher (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:502:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:559:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:683:18)
at Promise._fulfill (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:628:18)
at Promise._resolveCallback (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:423:57)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:514:17)
at Promise._settlePromise (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:559:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:683:18)
at Promise._fulfill (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:628:18)
at Promise._resolveCallback (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:423:57)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:514:17)
at Promise._settlePromise (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:559:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:683:18)
at Promise._fulfill (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:628:18)
at Promise._resolveCallback (C:\..\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:423:57)

[13:37:07] 'bundle' errored after 1.57 min

[13:37:07] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(bundle-dev)'

Message:

    bundle-dev promise
```

Does anyone know why this may be occuring? I'll try to update with any additional information that is needed.

Thank you so much.

### UPDATE 1

A part of the build step for this project is using aurelia-bundler to create javascript bundles that will be referenced by the app. This is mostly untouched from the aurelia skeleton. Knowing what code is at `line 13` is not really possible.

I attempted to upgrade Node from v4 to v6 but, the error persists. I went back to v4.4.4.

I also tried updating system-js configuration from within `config.js` to no avail.

Below are my current configurations:

**tasks/bundles.js**

```
module.exports = {
"bundles": {
    "dist/app-build": {
        "includes": [
            "[*.js]",
            "*.html!text",
            "*.css!text"
        ],
        "options": {
            "inject": true,
            "minify": true,
            "depCache": true,
            "rev": false
        }
    },
    "dist/aurelia": {
        "includes": [
            "aurelia-framework",
            "aurelia-bootstrapper",
            "aurelia-fetch-client",
            "aurelia-router",
            "aurelia-animator-css",
            "aurelia-templating-binding",
            "aurelia-polyfills",
            "aurelia-templating-resources",
            "aurelia-templating-router",
            "aurelia-loader-default",
            "aurelia-history-browser",
            "aurelia-logging-console",
            "bluebird",
            "jquery",
            "bootstrap",
            "bootstrap-notify",
            "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!text"
          ],
          "options": {
            "inject": true,
            "minify": true,
            "depCache": false,
            "rev": false
          }
    }
}};
```

**wwwroot/config.js**

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "./",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system"
    ]
  },
  paths: {
    "*": "dist/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },
  map: {
    "aurelia-animator-css": "npm:aurelia-animator-css@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
    "aurelia-dialog": "npm:aurelia-dialog@0.6.2",
    "aurelia-environment": "github:MarcScheib/aurelia-environment@0.1.6",
    "aurelia-fetch-client": "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@1.0.0-beta.1.2.5",
    "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.0-beta.1.2.5",
    "aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
    "aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
    "aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
    "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.0.0-beta.2.0.1",
    "aurelia-polyfills": "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.0.0-beta.1.1.6",
    "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.4",
    "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.2.4",
    "aurelia-templating-resources": "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6",
    "aurelia-templating-router": "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
    "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.8.38",
    "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.38",
    "bluebird": "npm:bluebird@2.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6",
    "bootstrap-notify": "npm:bootstrap-notify@3.1.3",
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.6",
    "dexie": "npm:dexie@1.3.6",
    "fetch": "github:github/fetch@0.11.1",
    "font-awesome": "npm:font-awesome@4.6.3",
    "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.2.4",
    "jquery-validation": "github:jzaefferer/jquery-validation@1.15.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "github:aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive@3.2.6",
    "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.3",
    "github:aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive@3.2.6": {
      "jquery-validation": "github:jzaefferer/jquery-validation@1.15.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
      "assert": "npm:assert@1.4.1"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0": {
      "buffer": "npm:buffer@3.6.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0": {
      "path-browserify": "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.11.3"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "github:jzaefferer/jquery-validation@1.15.0": {
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.2.4"
    },
    "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6": {
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.2.4"
    },
    "npm:assert@1.4.1": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-animator-css@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.7"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.6": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.0-beta.1.2.5",
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.0.0-beta.2.0.1",
      "aurelia-polyfills": "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.0.0-beta.1.1.6",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.4",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.7",
      "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.2.4",
      "aurelia-templating-resources": "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6",
      "aurelia-templating-router": "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-dialog@0.6.2": {
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.7"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.0-beta.1.2.5": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.6",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.7"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2": {
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.0.0-beta.2.0.1": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.0.0-beta.1.1.6": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.4": {
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3",
      "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-route-recognizer": "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.2.4": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.6",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.7"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.6",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.7"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.4",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.7"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.7": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.6",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1"
    },
    "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.38": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:bluebird@2.10.2": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:bootstrap-notify@3.1.3": {
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.2.4"
    },
    "npm:buffer@3.6.0": {
      "base64-js": "npm:base64-js@0.0.8",
      "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "ieee754": "npm:ieee754@1.1.6",
      "isarray": "npm:isarray@1.0.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:core-js@1.2.6": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:font-awesome@4.6.3": {
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.22"
    },
    "npm:inherits@2.0.1": {
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:process@0.11.3": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:util@0.10.3": {
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    }
  },
  bundles: {
    "app-build.js": [
      "app.html!github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.3.js",
      "app.js",
      "index.html!github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.3.js",
      "login.html!github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.3.js",
      "login.js",
      "main.js"
    ],
    "aurelia.js": [
      "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2.js",
      "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2/index.js",
      "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6.js",
      "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css!github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.3.js",
      "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js",
      "npm:aurelia-animator-css@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1.js",
      "npm:aurelia-animator-css@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/aurelia-animator-css.js",
      "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.6.js",
      "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.6/aurelia-binding.js",
      "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1.js",
      "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/aurelia-bootstrapper.js",
      "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3.js",
      "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js",
      "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1.js",
      "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/aurelia-event-aggregator.js",
      "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@1.0.0-beta.1.2.5.js",
      "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@1.0.0-beta.1.2.5/aurelia-fetch-client.js",
      "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.0-beta.1.2.5.js",
      "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.0-beta.1.2.5/aurelia-framework.js",
      "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1.js",
      "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/aurelia-history-browser.js",
      "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1.js",
      "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/aurelia-history.js",
      "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2.js",
      "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-loader-default.js",
      "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0.js",
      "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0/aurelia-loader.js",
      "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2.js",
      "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-logging-console.js",
      "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1.js",
      "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/aurelia-logging.js",
      "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1.js",
      "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/aurelia-metadata.js",
      "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.0.0-beta.2.0.1.js",
      "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.0.0-beta.2.0.1/aurelia-pal-browser.js",
      "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2.js",
      "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-pal.js",
      "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2.js",
      "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/aurelia-path.js",
      "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.0.0-beta.1.1.6.js",
      "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.0.0-beta.1.1.6/aurelia-polyfills.js",
      "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1.js",
      "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/aurelia-route-recognizer.js",
      "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.4.js",
      "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/aurelia-router.js",
      "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1.js",
      "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/aurelia-task-queue.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.2.4.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/aurelia-templating-binding.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/abstract-repeater.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/analyze-view-factory.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/array-repeat-strategy.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/aurelia-templating-resources.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/binding-mode-behaviors.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/binding-signaler.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/compile-spy.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/compose.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/css-resource.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/debounce-binding-behavior.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/dynamic-element.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/focus.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/hide.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/html-resource-plugin.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/html-sanitizer.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/if.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/map-repeat-strategy.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/null-repeat-strategy.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/number-repeat-strategy.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/repeat-strategy-locator.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/repeat-utilities.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/repeat.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/replaceable.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/sanitize-html.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/set-repeat-strategy.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/show.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/signal-binding-behavior.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/throttle-binding-behavior.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/update-trigger-binding-behavior.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/view-spy.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.6/with.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/aurelia-templating-router.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/route-href.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/route-loader.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/router-view.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.7.js",
      "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.7/aurelia-templating.js",
      "npm:bluebird@2.10.2.js",
      "npm:bluebird@2.10.2/js/browser/bluebird.js",
      "npm:bootstrap-notify@3.1.3.js",
      "npm:bootstrap-notify@3.1.3/bootstrap-notify.js",
      "npm:jquery@2.2.4.js",
      "npm:jquery@2.2.4/dist/jquery.js",
      "npm:process@0.11.3.js",
      "npm:process@0.11.3/browser.js"
    ]
  },
  depCache: {
    "login.js": [
      "aurelia-framework"
    ],
    "main.js": [
      "aurelia-fetch-client",
      "aurelia-environment",
      "aurelia-dialog",
      "bluebird",
      "bootstrap",
      "fetch"
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Node.js are you running?
If you're using Node v4 try Node v6 instead if you're able.

The message you're getting indicates a JavaScript parsing error of some sort, most likely caused by incomplete ES6 support in your runtime environment. So upgrading might make the problem go away. If not, what's on line: 13, col: 8 in your code? (as indicated in the error message)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I updated my question with the results and with my current configurations.

Comment: Hmm, if the issue is in the code you depend on then the outlook for getting this to work might not be so good. This framework mentions it's written in ss6. So if there's an option to compile the code down to es5 or es3, try that. Make sure this happens before the minification step. Also try skipping minification. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @DaveTemplin. I am trying to upgrade from es5 to es6 so I can use async/await, or at the very least, yield/generator functions. It may very well be that Aurelia simply won't work with es6 - which is VERY strange considering, like you said, it is written in es6 :) So off to Aurelia's Gitter discussions I go.